# Word cannot open the existing global template: Normal.dotm

Tags: ms-office

Almost once a day Word opens with the following error:

> Word cannot open the existing global template: Normal.dotm

I then delete `Normal.dotm` from `~/Library`

```
rm ./Group\ Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content.localized/Templates.localized/Normal.dotm
```

and reopen Word. The file is re-created and everything is fine. After some time (hours) it happens again.

This happens on two different machines with High Sierra (10.13.2) and Word 15.40 (171108)

Any solution? Any idea on what could corrupt `Normal.dotm`?

**Update**

When quitting word I also get (see comments) the message

> Changes have been made that affect the global template
>   Do you want to save those changes?

And I have no add-ins.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Are you using any Add-ins, by any chance?

Additionally, when I try to quit Word, a prompt with the message: "Changes have been made that affect the global template, . Do you want to save those changes?" appears... Do you get a message like this as well?

Comment: Do you save the changes?

Comment: @jmh I tried but with no changes